# Qt drag drop QTreeView to QLineEdit

Tags: drag-n-drop, qt

Собственно сабж с названии. Есть переопределенный treeview и из него нужно "дропнуть" в lineedit (тоже переопределенный, лежит на QDialog) данные. Подскажите какие event* и каких виджетов переопределять. Перепробовал переопределять эти методы как одного так и второго виджета. Нет пока нужного результата.

```
void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event);
void dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event);
void dropEvent(QDropEvent *event);
```

Answer (score 1):

Доброго времени суток!

Прочитайте в справке Qt вот этот [раздел](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/model-view-programming.html#using-drag-and-drop-with-item-views) - там все хорошо написано. Если вкратце, то Вам нет необходимости переопределять методы реакции на события в Вашем случае ни в одном, ни в другом классе. Для того чтобы заработал DnD (также вкратце) необходимо:

1. Переопределить `mimeTypes()` и `mimeData()` в Вашей **модели данных**.
2. Установить необходимые флаги для Вашего `QTreeView`: `QAbstractItemView::DragDropMode`.
3. Разрешить перетаскивание: `QTreeView::setDragEnabled(true)`

Для `QLineEdit` ничего переопределять не надо)

Более детально все описано в справке Qt)

Успехов!